# make file preprocessor directive

Tags: makefile, g++, c-preprocessor, compiler-options

I am not very experienced with make files and am trying to define a preprocessor variable in my make file,in Eclipse (linux).

It turns up a non trivial task,since as it seems am missing something...

Bellow you can find my make file's structure:

```
 var_first=g++

all:

    g++ main_cell.cpp -o hello
```

in this way am building my code,that i want to do is to define a variable in my make files that would then be asserted with an #ifdef,#endif in my code.

I have gone through numerous combinations but am missing some steps as it seems...

Could you please give some pointers?

Answer (score 5):

To add a definition while compiling, use the `-D` g++ option. Like this:

```
g++ -DMyDefine=123 main_cell.cpp -o hello
```

Now in `main_cell.cpp` you can do:

```
#if MyDefine == 123
   doStuff();
#endif
```

To use makefile variables for this, do something like:

```
all: g++ main_cell.cpp -o hello -Dvar_first=$(var_first)
```

That is equivalent of `#define var_first g++` in the .cpp file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the preprocessor variable directly to the compiler, you use a `-D` flag.

E.g. you want to define the variable `PRE_MY_VAR` to `1`, you can write:

```
g++ -o myexecutable *.cpp -DPRE_MY_VAR=1
```

So in your makefile this would be:

```
all:
    g++ main_cell.cpp -o hello -Dvar_first="g++"
```